# How to split string and form array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two string values and need to split the string if "," or "." is present and need to form an array.

```
$scope.welcome = "Welcome to Adityavani facitlity services,   please select from the following";

$scope.final = "Thanks for calling. You have registered successfully";
```

I need to create an array as below:

```
$scope.welcome_array = ["Welcome to Adityavani facitlity services", "please select from the following"];

$scope.final_array = ["Thanks for calling", "You have registered successfully"];
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$scope = {};
$scope.welcome = "Welcome to Adityavani facitlity services,   please select from the following";
$scope.final = "Thanks for calling. You have registered successfully";
$scope.splitSrting=function(splitStr){
var reg=/[,.]\s*/;
return splitStr.split(reg);
}
console.log($scope.splitSrting($scope.welcome));
console.log($scope.splitSrting($scope.final));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.welcome = "Welcome to Adityavani facitlity services,   please select from the following";
$scope.final = "Thanks for calling. You have registered successfully";
```

JS native [split([separator[, limit]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the regular expression(`/[,.]\s*/`) as separator:

```
$scope.welcome_array = $scope.welcome.split(/[,.]\s*/);
$scope.final_array = $scope.final.split(/[,.]\s*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.welcome_array = $scope.welcome.split(/[,.]\s*/);
   $scope.final_array = $scope.final.split(/[,.]\s*/);
```

**split** will be used to split the string and it return the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the following regular expression:

```
/[,.]\s*/
```

```js
$scope = {};

$scope.welcome = "Welcome to Adityavani facitlity services,   please select from the following";
$scope.final = "Thanks for calling. You have registered successfully";

$scope.welcome_array = $scope.welcome.split(/[,.]\s*/);
$scope.final_array = $scope.final.split(/[,.]\s*/);

console.log($scope.welcome_array);
console.log($scope.final_array);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$scope.welcome = $scope.welcome.split(",");
$scope.final = $scope.final.split(".");
```