# Split string at numbers within single indexed array to form new indices javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

An extension of [How to split string and form array using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360290/how-to-split-string-and-form-array-using-angularjs)

I have an array with a single index below:

["1. Get into car.2. Buckle seat belt.3. Start Ignition"]

What want to accomplish is to split the string at each step so that in the end I have an array of steps shown below

["1. Get into car.", "2. Buckle seat belt.", "3. Start Ignition"]

How do I accomplish this using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const arr = ["1. Get into car.2. Buckle seat belt.3. Start Ignition"];
const result = arr[0].match( /\d+\D*/g );
console.log( result );
```